# Evaluate a string in wp7/wp8

Tags: windows, string, xaml, sdk, eval

I am currently doing my first application in the wp8 sdk and have come across a problem.
What I want to do is when the user clicks a hyperlink button, it evaluates a bound textbox (author) and send it as a search string to google.

"http://www.google.com/search?q="

Now I tried using the Eval method that is available in asp.net; but it did not work. I have also tried to find alternatives for it, but not much luck there either.

So my question is. Is there any way to send a search string to google, evaluating a string?

Just to mention, all of this is in windows phone 8 sdk. And is within a datatemplate.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Setting the `NavigateUri` and `Target` on the `HyperlinkButton` should navigate to the web site. To construct the `NavigateUri` to include user input you can add an extra string property alongside your already bound `Author` property (wherever that lives) and just expose the root "http://www.google.com/search?q=" + `Author`. Once you have that bound to `NavigateUri` (and getting property change notifications along with `Author`) the button should launch with the user entered text included.